# How to get current user inside a class (not a component) in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, identity

I have a Hub class `public class TestHub: Hub` and i want to get the current user inside `OnConnectedAsync()` method.

so for a have tried different approaches including this:

```
private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authp;

public TestHub(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
{
_authp = authenticationStateProvider;
}
public override async Task<Task> OnConnectedAsync()
{
var user = (await _authp.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
}
```

But it is not returnng anything

Answer (score 0):

Because you'd like to import `AuthenticationStateProvider` through dependency injection, so your class must also be instantiated through dependency injection.

First create an interface as follows:

```
public interface ITestHub
{
    public Task<Task> OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Then inherit from this interface as follows:

```
public class TestHub:ITestHub
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authp;
    public TestHub(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authp = authenticationStateProvider;
    }
    public async Task<Task> OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var user = (await _authp.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
    }
}
```

Now you have to add this class in IoC as follows in the startup.cs or program.cs

```
services.AddScoped<ITestHub, TestHub>();
```

It's a sample code according to your code. Because you didn't include the `Hub` class structure, so I wasn't sure if dependency injection can be done through the same? Anyway, this is how it works.